# How can I add more tags on the 'popular repositories' repos, which are displayed on my profile page?

Tags: git, github

Just noticed that GitHub updated the UI on my profile page. 
How can I add more tags on the 'popular repositories' repos, which are displayed on my profile page?

For example, in the image you can see the yellow circle and 'JavaScript'. How could I add more tags next to it? Is it possible?

I tried to look at the documentation, but didn't find an answer on how to add them. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GitHub help pages](//help.github.com/articles/pinning-repositories-to-your-profile/):

> You can pin repositories to your profile so that other people can easily see repositories you own or have contributed to. These pinned repositories include important information about the repository, like a summary of the work being done, the number of stars the repository has received, and **the main programming language** used in the repository.

[Emphasis added.]

So the language that is shown is the primary language of the repository. To answer your question: No, it doesn't appear to be possible to change or add to the language tags. (I also looked through the UI and settings pages to confirm this.)

You may want to [contact GitHub support](//github.com/contact) to request this feature.